# monitor calibration on 20.04?

Tags: display, 20.04, screen, monitor

I have been searching, but I have found nothing conclusive, about which colourmeters are supported by Ubuntu software?

Anyone with experiences in monitor-calibration on 20.04?

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: In ubuntu device settings there is a `Device Colour Profiles` section or probably `Device Color Profiles` in US English. And I think the underlying system for this is called `colord` so you could search using those terms. Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_color_management

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is this page https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrationdevices.html.en as of writing it states:

> **What color measuring instruments are supported?**
>
> GNOME relies on the Argyll color management system to support color
> instruments. Thus the following display measuring instruments are
> supported:
>
> ```
> Gretag-Macbeth i1 Pro (spectrometer)
>
> Gretag-Macbeth i1 Monitor (spectrometer)
>
> Gretag-Macbeth i1 Display 1, 2 or LT (colorimeter)
>
> X-Rite i1 Display Pro (colorimeter)
>
> X-Rite ColorMunki Design or Photo (spectrometer)
>
> X-Rite ColorMunki Create (colorimeter)
>
> X-Rite ColorMunki Display (colorimeter)
>
> Pantone Huey (colorimeter)
>
> MonacoOPTIX (colorimeter)
>
> ColorVision Spyder 2 and 3 (colorimeter)
>
> Colorimètre HCFR (colorimeter)
> ```
>
> ***The Pantone Huey is currently the cheapest and best supported hardware in Linux.***

**For Calibration:**

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrate-screen.html.en:

> **How do I calibrate my screen?**
>
> You can calibrate your screen so that it shows more accurate color.
> This is especially useful if you are involved in digital photography,
> design or artwork.
>
> You will need either a colorimeter or a spectrophotometer to do this.
> Both devices are used to profile screens, but they work in slightly
> different ways.
>
> ```
> Make sure your calibration device is connected to your computer.
>
> Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.
>
> Click on Settings.
>
> Click Devices in the sidebar.
>
> Click Color in the sidebar to open the panel.
>
> Select your screen.
>
> Press Calibrate… to commence the calibration.
> ```
>
> Screens change all the time: the backlight in a TFT display will halve
> in brightness approximately every 18 months, and will get yellower as
> it gets older. This means you should recalibrate your screen when the
> [!] icon appears in the Color panel.
>
> LED screens also change over time, but a much slower rate than TFT

The Official Documentation also has extensive Information regarding Color here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color.html.en

Comment: Does this actually work? I connect an i1pro, press calibrate, go through the choices and it crashes at the first patch. I haven't much faith in the settings app, had no joy trying to create paper profiles with it in 18.04lts, haven't tried yet in 20.04 but I don't hold out much hope. Displaycal seems unsuported now and might not run as it has not been updated to python3, I think. So it's down to using argyll at the command line which is pretty tough going as there are a lot of options for technical stuff to get your head round.

Comment: I think the Pantone Huey is now out of production.

Comment: The Calibrate button is disabled without any indication why